# Run an async process in a sync method without waiting for that process to finish, but keep request alive until it does

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asynchronous, synchronization, httprequest

So I am using the `Global.asax` `Application_BeginRequest` to kick off a background task like this:

```
processor.RunAllAsync()
            .ContinueWith(x => x.Exception.LogError(), 
                               TaskContinuationOptions.OnlyOnFaulted);
```

I need this process to not block the user making the web request from seeing the requested content (ie, I do not want to `await` it), but the problem is that right now the process is being aborted once the `HTTP request` is over.

So, how do I kick off an `async` process in a sync method without blocking the `HTTP request` from doing its thing, and also not killing this process when the `HTTP request` is over?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I need this process to not block the user making the web request from seeing the requested content

Are you sure? Most clients can make an HTTP request and just not wait for the result.

> So, how do I kick off an async process in a sync method without blocking the HTTP request from doing its thing, and also not killing this process when the HTTP request is over?

This has nothing to do with `async` or `await`. As I describe on my blog, [`async` does not change the HTTP protocol](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/08/async-doesnt-change-http-protocol.html).

What you're asking for is "fire and forget". Note that this is very dangerous on ASP.NET, since IIS/ASP.NET are not designed to do work *outside* of a request context. It's far better if you can keep the work as part of the request, and just have the *client* do fire-and-forget.

But if you really want to... I describe the various approaches in my [blog post on fire-and-forget on ASP.NET](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2014/06/fire-and-forget-on-asp-net.html). In summary, the most reliable way of doing fire-and-forget on ASP.NET is to have the request handler put the work into a reliable queue, and have an *independent process* read from that queue and do the actual work. However, if you don't need reliability (i.e., you're OK with occasionally losing work), then you can just use `HostingEnvironment.QueueBackgroundWorkItem`, as such:

```
HostingEnvironment.QueueBackgroundWorkItem(_ => processor.RunAllAsync());
```